# Working with Unity, Triggers not working

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine, triggers

So i'm finishing up my Unity Project for school until i ran into this problem, the Triggers wont work if i try to make it detect the object's (that it is running into) name or tag.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D() {
    if(gameObject.name == "AntiDome")
    {
    Debug.Log ("TESTX");
    }
}
```

This doesn't, and ive tried several alternatives with the same purpose, but

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D() {
    Debug.Log ("TESTX");
}
```

Works fine on its own, i have no clue why. I've been at this for hours and i really don't know what to do next.

Comment: Do you check the unity physic layers? goto `Edit > Project Settings > Physics 2D`

Comment: Yeah i have, The object I'm trying to move is labeled as Xtra while the AntiDome is Default, but they should still collide. The Object does Trigger AntiDome but only when it doesn't say

void OnTriggerEnter2D() {
    if(gameObject.name == "AntiDome")
    {
    Debug.Log ("TESTX");
    }
}

Comment: do you check my answer? If it works please mark it as answer .thanks and good luck.

Comment: Omg i think it works now, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right implementation of `OnTriggerEnter2D()`.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log (other);

    // Put your condition here.
    // ex: if (other.gameObject.name == "AntiDome")
    //     {
    //         Debug.Log("TEST");
    //     {
}
```